# Understanding the apply method example in functional programming in Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

I am reading the Eloquent JavaScript and I got to [Functional programming (chapter 6)](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html). I am confused by the following example:

```
show(Math.min.apply(null, [5, 6]));

function negate(func) {
  return function() {
    return !func.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}
```

*Note: The show() simply prints out the output to the console on the Eloquent JavaScript website.

I don't get how the negate() function is related to the code within show(). Where is the negate() function called? I don't see that it was used anywhere in that example, or am I wrong?

Comment: These look like two distinct snippets to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code given contains *two* examples.  Every function has an `apply` method.  In the first example, `Math.min`'s `apply` method is used to call `Math.min` with the argument list `[5,6]`.  The second example should be viewed in contrast to the preceding example in which `negate` is defined as

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
```

In that example, `negate(func)` returns a new function *of one argument* that calls `func` with that single argument, negates the result, and returns it.  What happens if `func` expects more than one argument, though?  That's what this example covers.

```
function negate(func) {
  return function() {
    return !func.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}
```

In this definition, `negate(func)` returns a new function *of an arbitrary number of arguments* that calls `func` with the list of provided arguments, negates the result, and returns it.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. I just wish the author had written it this way as well.

Answer (score 1):

That part of the book was to explain that some functions take multiple parameters, so you must call the `func` parameter with `.apply()` instead of just `func(x)`.

The first example used `NaN`, which accepts one parameter. That's why it worked to use:

```
return !func(x);
```

But some functions, like `Math.min`, accept several parameters. Technically, when using `negate`, you don't know what function will be passed, and what arguments will be passed. Therefore, you can't hardcode in `x` being passed to `func`. Using `.apply()`, you can pass the original arguments, `arguments`, to the `func` call.

Reference:

- `apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like that could have been explained by the book author in a better and less confusing way. Usually when you find code snippets in those examples it's all related to each other. This one for some reason gives two distinct snippets of code without any notice to the user.

Comment: @SineLaboreNihil Haha I completely agree! I think it was organized/worded very weirdly. Do these new answers help you understand the point of it? Or do you need more of an explanation?

Comment: I understand it now. Too bad I couldn't get simple explanations like these in the book. Thanks for the help to all of you. I really appreciate it.